# How to set limit to pagination?

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, pagination, playframework-2.1

I want to use pagination and I did it but I am not getting that part I want. I want through some solution but still not getting.

What am I doing is:

**query part in model:**

```
public static Page<User> page(int page, int pageSize, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {


        return find.where()
                .ilike("name", "%" + filter + "%")
                .orderBy(sortBy + " " + order)
                .findPagingList(pageSize)
                .getPage(page);
    }
```

**view part:**

```
@(currentPage: com.avaje.ebean.Page[User], currentSortBy: String, currentOrder: String, currentFilter: String,ud: String)

@****************************************
* Helper generating navigation links    *
****************************************@
@link(newPage:Int, newSortBy:String) = @{

    var sortBy = currentSortBy
    var order = currentOrder

    if(newSortBy != null) {
        sortBy = newSortBy
        if(currentSortBy == newSortBy) {
            if(currentOrder == "asc") {
                order = "desc"
            } else {
                order = "asc"
            }
        } else {
            order = "asc"
        }
    }

    // Generate the link
    routes.paging.pag(newPage, sortBy, order, currentFilter)

}



@header(key:String, title:String) = {


        <a class="@key.replace(".","_") header @if(currentSortBy == key) @{if(currentOrder == "asc") "headerSortDown" else "headerSortUp"}" href="@link(0,key)">@title</a>


}


@main("welcome to EXTR ") {

<div class="container-narrow">


      <div class="masthead">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">

            <li><a href="@routes.paging.extrad(ud)" >Extr resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="@routes.signin.logou">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3 class="muted">
            welcome admin</b>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <hr><div  align="center">
            <h1> @currentPage.getTotalRowCount() user found</h1>
            @if(currentPage.getTotalRowCount == 0) {

        <div class="well">
            <em>Nothing to display</em>
        </div>

    } else {



           <table border="1" >
           <tr>
           <th>@header("name","name")</th>
           <th>@header("email","email")</th>
           <th>@header("","")</th>
            </tr>

            <tbody>

                @for(user <- currentPage.getList) {

                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="">@user.name</a></td>
                        <td>
                            @user.getEmail()
                        </td>



                        <td><a href="@routes.update.del(user.id)" class="btn success" style="color:#008000; ">delete</a></td>
                        </tr>}
                        </tbody>
                        </table>







    <div id="pagination" class="pagination">
            <ul>
                @if(currentPage.hasPrev) {
                    <li class="prev">
                        <a href="@link(currentPage.getPageIndex - 1, null)">&larr; Previous</a>
                    </li>
                } else {
                    <li class="prev disabled">
                        <a>&larr; Previous</a>
                    </li>
                }
               @for(i <- 0 until currentPage.getTotalPageCount()){
            <li><a  href="@link(i, null)">@(i+1)</a></li>
        }
                @if(currentPage.hasNext) {
                    <li class="next">
                        <a href="@link(currentPage.getPageIndex + 1, null)">Next &rarr;</a>
                    </li>
                } else {
                    <li class="next disabled">
                        <a>Next &rarr;</a>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>

     </div>

    }


     </div>

   </div>

}
```

and what am I getting is:

[image]

but what I want is

at a time I want to show to 5 pages and when click on 5th page it again get to 5-10 pages. But my pagination is getting all pages at a time.

I want the numbers to be displayed in this format..

```
1 2 3 4 5 ^
```

where if I press 5, then it should display from 5 to 10

```
5 6 7 8 9 10
```

till the max records are available. I just want to know a how to do this for displaying numbers.

give me some idea to do this.

Comment: You should have currentpage as the main reference and add +1 and +2 also -1 and -2 and after that add<< >> as first page and final page.Just check for all logical possibilities assumed in this scheme.(for example,if currentpage is 1 than -1 page and -2 page shoudnt exist etc.)

Comment: could you please tell me some example of this ?

Comment: Here is a clear example in PHP but you could adapt it. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8xYGnEOXYc